# Ошибка подрузки изменений таблицы, после изменений в клиенте

Tags: c#, sql, исключения, datagridview

возникла проблема в методе ниже:

```
private void dtIngredient_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    Table ingredients = new Table();
    if (DataBase.Connect())
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dtIngredient.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString()))
        {
            if (newRowI == true)
            {
                ingredients.Query("INSERT INTO ingredients (Ingredient) VALUES ('" + dtIngredient.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value + "')");
                object DishId = ingredients.Query("SELECT ID FROM ingredients ORDER BY ID DESC");
                composition.Query("INSERT INTO composition (DishID, IngredientID) VALUES (" + dtDish.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value + "," + DishId + ")");
            }
            else
                ingredients.Query("UPDATE ingredients SET Ingredient = '" + dtIngredient.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value + "' WHERE ID = " + dtIngredient.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value);
        }
        else
            ingredients.Query("DELETE FROM ingredients WHERE ID = " + dtIngredient.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value); 

        //Ниже исключение, при попытке загрузить таблицу еще раз
        dtIngredient.DataSource = composition.newTable("SELECT composition.ID, ingredients.Ingredient FROM composition " +
                "INNER JOIN ingredients ON ingredients.Id = composition.IngredientID " +
                "WHERE DishID = " + dtDish.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value);
        DataBase.Close();
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Проверте подключение к базе данных", "Ошибка Подключения", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Данный метод вызывался при окончании редактирования ячейки и я могу отредактировать ячейку и все пройдет хорошо, но если в это время кликнуть на другую ячейку то мы получим исключение, а конкретнее при попытке получить таблицу еще раз, после всех изменений я получаю исключение: 
`Недопустимая операция: приводит к повторному вызову функции SetCurrentCellAddressCore.`

Я смотрел при каких условиях возникает вызов `SetCurrentCellAddressCore` и пошел исправлять, я принудительно покидал фокус ячейки, но это вызывало событие в котором все и есть ошибка, т.е. `private void dtIngredient_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)`
Пробовал отчищать таблицу и потом ее загружать, но я получал исключение, что нельзя отчистить этот список
Надеюсь я описал понятно

Comment: Какие еще обработчики событий навешаны на datagridview?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, `private void dtIngredient_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)`, в этом методе мы определяем переменную `newRowI` коротая показывает нам добавляем мы новою строку или изменяем текущую, можно было бы использовать `isNewRow`, но как только мы кликаем на новую строку `isNewRow == false`, надо ее как-то запомнить, код в этом методе простой мы просто с помощью `isNewRow`, меняем поле `newRowI`

Comment: Кстати, на ходу у DataGridView менять DadaSource плохая изначально идея, ибо структура столбцов DataGridView настроена на конкретное табличное представление, и неизвестно, что там происходит с этими настройками при смене источника. ИМХО лучше, если без этого нельзя обойтись, работать с методами dtIngredient.DataSource, не меняя источник.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов, Полностью  с вами согласен, я использую только одну таблицу, для одного dataGridView, для минимизации , проблем, было бы круто, просто редактировать информацию только в источнике данных, а потом его переподключать к таблице или выйдет одно и тоже?

Comment: [это?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26522927/how-to-evade-reentrant-call-to-setcurrentcelladdresscore)?

Comment: @tym32167, Да, ошибка аналогична, я так полагаю это и будет решением

Comment: Так у вас запросы `ingredients.Query`/`composition.newTable` выполняются в другом потоке?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я так понял, там ошибка в том, что автор пытается изменить грид в то время, как текущая процедура изменения грида ещё не закончена. Видимо, чтобы дождаться окончания текущего изменения, а уже потом вносить новое, в том ответе советуют просто новое изменение отправить в диспетчер - так как диспетчер его запустит точно уже после выхода из текущей функции, так как текушая функция в диспетчере и выполняется :)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, нет, думаю мне следует выделить отделенный поток, а ошибка хорошо описана комментатором выше, я меню грид до завершения редактирования, Я думал, что событие `EndEdit` возникает после завершения редактирования ячейки